# Rails: How to pass index object into controller for further sorting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In our rails 3.2 app, there is a need passing index object created by action index to controller again for further sorting. It can be done if the further sorting action is in controller. However we would like to share the further sorting action among different models.

Here is the action `list_open_proces`s in `quotes controller` (working!):

```
def list_open_process 
  index()
  @quotes = return_open_process(@quotes)  #sorting @quotes with @quotes.where(...)
end
```

`@quotes` is the variable holding the returns by action `index`. In method `return_open_process`, `@quotes` is sorted again. We would like to make action list_open_process more generic among different models.

Here is one solution we tried and failed.

We replace `@quotes` with var `model` and pass name of @quotes in params[:model_var] as string of '@quotes':

```
def list_open_process 
  index()
  model = eval(params[:model_var])  #params[:model_var] returns '@quotes'
  model = return_open_process(model) 
end
```

We hook up debug and this is what we found:

1. model == @quotes return true in action `list_open_process` and in method `return_open_process`
2. In method `return_open_process`, model is Quote class and is equal to @quotes.
3. @quotes is not sorted at all after method `return_open_process`.

What's right way to pass @quotes (`model` for more generic) for further sorting?

Comment: please do not use `eval`, especially passing user input, opens you to all kinds of code injection exploits, i.e. `http://localhost:3000/quotes/list_open_process?model_var=User.delete_all` - now all of your users are gone

Comment: We decide to keep the method list_open_process in individual controller instead of making it generic and introducing security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code will be much clearer and reusable if you don't directly call index() from list_open_process, but instead move the part that populates @quotes to another method or object. For instance:

```
def index
  # do other stuff first?
  @quotes = get_quotes
end

def list_open_process
  @quotes = return_open_process(get_quotes)
end

def get_quotes
  # extracted from the index() method
end
private :get_quotes
```

Now, the intention is clearer, and you aren't doing any extra steps that index might execute that aren't needed by list_open_process.

As for making it more flexible, depending on size you might consider a case statement that matches a param string like 'quotes' to the method that gets quotes, and so on. Or use a hash of keywords to method references. The point is, you want to make sure that you ONLY execute code when an allowed keyword type is passed, and any other ones get ignored or trigger an error message back to the client.

Comment: Case command can't be used because we don't know beforehand which controller is going to run against with list_open_process. All code in action index needs to be executed before further sorting.

Comment: If all the code in action index is fetching or updating data, and you need to execute it all, then you should move ALL of the code out of index into another service object (that you can call from any controller), and make action index into just a one or two liner that calls the service object. Now anything else that you think needs to execute index, can use that service object. Limit your controller actions to dealing with params and rendering.